# Make string with separator from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i try to convert pandas column to string with "," for adding it to http query.

```
       ID
0      702
1      707
2      307
```

And, i will get this string(mystr)

```
702,707,307
```

After adding to url string

"http://example.com/ids=" + mystr

Comment: `out = ','.join(df['ID'].astype(str))`

Comment: is 302 typo? if yes, use @mozway's code

Comment: all comment yes, thanks guys!